# Google cloud kubernetes start docker container image with parameters such as --runtime=nvidia

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I want google cloud kubernetes to run my docker image with images. such as:

```
docker run -it --runtime=nvidia --volume path_to_data:/root/data my_image
```

How to configure these parameters?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on Registry visibility.

For public images such as `nginx` it's simple:

Just run:

```sh
kubectl run mynginx --image=nginx
```

There is good explanation: [Running a Docker Container on Google Container Engine - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yji-nfuUvIo)

As for Private registry, there are many cases.

According to manual: [Images - Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/)

> #### [Using a Private Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-a-private-registry)
>
> Private registries may require keys to read images from them. Credentials can be provided in several ways:
>
> Using Google Container Registry
>
> - Per-cluster
> - automatically configured on Google Compute Engine or Google Kubernetes Engine
> - all pods can read the project’s private registry
>
> #### [Using Google Container Registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-google-container-registry)
>
> Kubernetes has native support for the [Google Container Registry (GCR)](https://cloud.google.com/tools/container-registry/), when running on Google Compute Engine (GCE). If you are running your cluster on GCE or Google Kubernetes Engine, simply use the full image name (e.g. gcr.io/my_project/image:tag).
>
> All pods in a cluster will have read access to images in this registry.
>
> The kubelet will authenticate to GCR using the instance’s Google service account. The service account on the instance will have a `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only`, so it can pull from the project’s GCR, but not push

So, to run image from gcr.io, you can

```sh
kubectl run myapp --image=gcr.io/my_project/image:tag
```

Comment: I found yourself as google kubernetes expert. Are you familiar with video transcoding on gke gpu accelerated clusters? gpu drivers, cuda, ffmpeg, etc...